# Parallelogram inside of a quadrilateral.

Tags: geometry

> **Prove:** If $ABCD$ is a quadrilateral with respective side midpoints $X$; $Y$; $Z$; $W$, as pictured, then $XYZW$ is a parallelogram.
>
> [image]

I'm not sure where to start. All I know is $\overline{DZ}=\overline{XC}$, $\overline{DW}=\overline{WA}$. $\overline{AX}=\overline{XB}$ and $\overline{BY}=\overline{YC}$. From here I don't see where I can go.

Comment: Midsegment of a triangle is always parallel to the third edge of the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find parallel lines. In particular, show that $WZ$ is parallel to some other line. Show that $XY$ is also parallel to that other line.

**Hint:** What do you know about mid points of 2 line segments which a common end point?

Comment: do i have to draw lines in to show WZ and XY to them?

Comment: @user60887 Yes you do. But there aren't many lines to draw. Use the 2nd hint.

Comment: ok thanks I can get it from here. I just wasn't sure what to use.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- For any $\triangle ABC$, let $M$ and $N$ be the midpoints of $AB$ and $AC$, then $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle AMN$, moreover, all the sides of the first triangle are parallel respectively to the sides of the second triangle (see also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem)).

Good luck ;-)